# Optimising a multivariate table of counts based on marginals

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, python, optimization, data-transformation

I've been stuck on a problem for a very long time now so I decided to post on this forum for the first time. Although I am using code to perform this task, I believe it uses some statistics and I would love to get some insight.

I have 4 datasets that consist of the columns:

- area, age, count
- area, sex, count
- area, ethnicity, count
- age, sex, ethnicity, count

I am aiming to create data that gets counts for all combinations of area, age, sex, ethnicity. My original approach was to make the counts in the datasets proportions, join them on the area, multiply the proportions then adjust them to sum to 1 again. I can then use the sum of all counts to turn these back to integers. The problem is that the summed counts for each dataset is different; I feel that my method is "cheating" and cannot be explained with theory. To combat this and possibly optimise the output through iterations, I found a concept called IPF and attempted to implement this method. I could not get it to work and I am having difficulty in approaching this task.

1. Is this a viable approach for this problem?
2. If so, could someone with more expertise give somewhat detailed steps I could try implementing?
3. If not, what are some other alternative methods I could try?